# Alternative proof of Uniform Boundedness Principle

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The easiest proof of the Uniform Boundedness Principle uses the Baire Category Theorem. I'm trying to follow one which doesn't directly use it. Let $X$ be a Banach Space and $Y$ a normed vector space, $T_\alpha$ a family of continuous linear operators from $X$ to $Y$.

Suppose $||T_\alpha||$ is unbounded. Then we can find a subsequence $||T_{\alpha_{n+1}}|| > (100)^n ||T_{\alpha_n}||$. We can find some $x_n \in X$ so that $||T_{\alpha_n} x_n||_Y \geq 0.5||T_{\alpha_n}||$.

Next, we let $x = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \epsilon_m 10^{-m} x_m$ where $\epsilon_m \in \{ 1, -1\}$. Then the claim is that we can choose $\epsilon_n$ (assuming $\epsilon_1$, ..., $\epsilon_{n-1}$ have been chosen) such that $||T_{\alpha_n} (\sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m 10^{-m} x_m)||_Y \geq \frac{1}{4} 10^{-n}||T_{\alpha_n}||$.

Why can we always change the sign to ensure the last condition is true?

Comment: Well, using the Baire Category Theorem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any two vectors $v,w$ in a normed space, the triangle inequality implies
$$
\|v+w\|+\|v-w\|\ge 2\|w\|
$$
hence at least one of the terms $\|v+w\|$ and $\|v-w\|$ must be $\ge \|w\|$.

In this proof,  $x_n$ is chosen so that 
$$\|T_{\alpha_n} ( 10^{-n} x_n)\|_Y = 10^{-n}\|T_{\alpha_n}(x_n) \|_Y\ge \frac12 10^{-n}\|T_{\alpha_n}\|$$
Hence, $\epsilon_n\in\{-1,1\}$ can be chosen so that 
$$\|T_{\alpha_n} (\sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m 10^{-m} x_m)\|_Y \geq \frac{1}{2} 10^{-n}\|T_{\alpha_n}\|$$
Your source claims this inequality with $1/4$ on the right.